# How to configure failover for a cosmosdb serverless account?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, serverless

CosmosDB serverless account doesn’t support automatic-failover? I have checked for documentation and SLA and have not found anywhere on how to configure serverless account failover etc.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is NO, have you looked at the [serverless](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/serverless) documentation.

> A serverless account can only run in a single Azure region. It is not
> possible to add additional Azure regions to a serverless account after
> you create it.

which means you cannot configure by any ways.

Comment: Oh that's something i have not come across. Thanks